# Kafka Streams not writing expected result after countByKey

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Using Kafka Streams (version 0.10.0.1) and Kafka Broker (0.10.0.1) I'm trying to generate counts based on message keys.  I produce my messages with the following command:

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic kafka-streams-topic --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=,
```

When I run the above command I can send a key and value like this:

```
1,{"value":10}
```

This will send a message to kafka that has a key = 1 and a value = {"value":10}.

My goal is to then count how many messages have the key=1.  Given the above commands the count would be 1.

Here is the code that I am using:

```java
public class StreamProcessor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

        final Serde<Long> longSerde = Serdes.Long();
        final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();

        KStream<String, String> values = builder.stream(stringSerde, stringSerde, "kafka-streams-topic");

        KStream<String, Long> counts = values
                .countByKey(stringSerde, "valueCounts")
                .toStream();

        counts.print(stringSerde, longSerde);
        counts.to(stringSerde, longSerde, "message-counts-topic");

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, properties());

        streams.start();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
    }

    private static Properties properties() {
        final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();

        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kafka-streams-poc");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_CONFIG, "localhost:2181");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());

        return streamsConfiguration;
    }
}
```

When I run counts.print(stringSerde,longSerde) I get:

```
1 , 1
```

Meaning that I have a key=1 and their is 1 message that has that key.  That is what I expect.

However, when the following line runs:

```java
counts.to(stringSerde, longSerde, "message-counts-topic");
```

The topic called message-counts-topic gets a message sent to it but when I try to read the message using this command:

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic message-counts-topic --property print.key=true --property key.separator=, --from-beginning
```

I get the following output:

```
1 ,
```

Where the 1 is the key and nothing is displayed for the value.  I expect to see the message 1 , 1.  But for some reason the count value is lost, even though its displayed when calling the print method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a different value deserializer for `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh`. Add the following:

```
--property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer
```

Default String deserializer fails to read the long value correctly.

Comment: Here is the complete command:

/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic message-counts-topic --property print.key=true --property key.separator=, --property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer --from-beginning